# How to make a start on this Erlang homework?

Tags: erlang

Here is my challenge:

1. Create a function `exists` that returns `true` or `false` when an item is in the list.

   ```
   1> exists(2,[1,4,5,3,2]).
   true
   2> exists(2,[]).
   false
   3> exists(2,[4,5,6,7]).
   false
   ```
2. Create a function `listLength` that will return the length of a list. Using the native function length is not allowed.

   ```
   1> listLength([1,2,3]).
   3
   2> listLength([]).
   0
   ```

Comment: what have tried so far to implement? Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i edited it sir. sorry

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Show what code you have written to solve your problems.

Answer (score 3):

AS it looks like homework, I hope you will not get the solution here. I will give you some clues.

For the first one:

- there is one case when you know for sure that the term does not exist in the list: when the list is empty.
- When the list is not empty the only element of the list you can access is the head of the list, so you will have to use recursion to compare one by one every elements of the list to the input term.

Same thing for the second:

- you know the length of an empty list: 0
- you know that the length of a not empty list is 1 + length of the tail. Use recursion to count one by one all the elements.